# Use box shadow on an element with padding instead of margins

Tags: html, css

Menu with a box shadow. I need to give it a padding top of 30px instead of margin-top so that when the parent has hovered, the sub menu appears and stays appeared when the cursor moves down into space between. If I give it margin-top 30px then the box-shadow works fine, but the submenu disappears when moving the cursor down away from the parent item

Here is a picture of what it looks like

[image]

As you can see there is padding at the top of the submenu but the box shadow gets affected by the padding.

Is there any way to have the box shadow go to the top edge of the first white list item instead of pushing it down and creating that transparent area while keeping the padding?

Here is the bare bones code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">text
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
 li {
     position: relative;
 }

 .menu-item-has-children:hover .submenu {
     display: none;
 }

 .menu-item-has-children:hover .submenu {
      display: block;
      padding-top: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 }
```

Anyone have an idea how to overcome this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post working fiddle that you have shown in your image.

Answer (score 3):

I realize I'm very late to the party on this but I had a similar issue and found this post while looking for a solution. I thought I'd go ahead and add an answer that might be useful to someone in the future. Instead of box-shadow, use filter:drop-shadow. This ignores the box model and only affects the dropdown element itself.

Something like this should have worked for you:

```
 .menu-item-has-children:hover .submenu {
     display: block;
     padding-top: 30px;
     position: absolute;
     filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15));
 }
```

Answer (score -4):

Firstly you really shouldn't tell it to hide when hovering when you want it to show. Secondly giving the submenu an absolute position takes it out of the flow of the page and causes it to stop being "inside" the parent li.

Stop it being absolute and you should stop having problems.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: It is an answer. Remove the position: absolute; from the second level. it's pulling it out of the stream and preventing it from working.

Comment: A complete answer would include a demonstration/example of the correct code. Edit your answer to include an example, and you will receive much better feedback :) (this is also a great way to make sure you get your hands on those upvotes that we all love so much).

Comment: it needs to be position absolute because it needs to be separated from the parent